# React: Image source that uses component variable is case-sensitive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component (an allergy "card") that uses the variable's name to assign an image as the background.

```
<div className="allergen-card-contents">
    <div className="allergen-image-container" style={{backgroundImage: `url('/icons/allergens/${allergy.name}.png')`,}}>
    </div>
    <p className="allergen-title">{allergy.name}</p>
 </div>
```

I have a folder with all of the allergy card icons in them, and it works for all of them - unless the {allergy.name} has a capital letter. Note - I cannot edit the name of the allergen to make it lowercase. For example:

[image]

I know that Javascript is case sensitive - but when I change the filenames of the icons to match the case of "AIP" and "Anti-Candida", it makes no difference on whether the image shows up or not.

Interestingly enough, if I go into the page inspector, and change the case to "aip.png" or "AiP.png", the image renders. I'm new to React, so this may be something obvious that I'm missing, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if all images have lowercae names then `${allergy.name.toLowerCase()}.png` ?

Comment: How are the images named on the server-side? All lower-case?

Comment: are you placing the images inside the `public` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try renaming your image files to all lowercase and updating your component name based on image file name.

Or you may use the `toLowerCase()` method to convert the `allergy.name` variable to lowercase before using it in the image URL. This way, the URL would always use lowercase letters regardless of the case of allergy.name.

##### Example:

```js
<div className="allergen-card-contents">
  <div className="allergen-image-container" style={{backgroundImage: `url('/icons/allergens/${allergy.name.toLowerCase()}.png')`,}}>
  </div>
  <p className="allergen-title">{allergy.name}</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple like this. Appreciate it